# How to add menu SALE with submenus which will show only products on sale?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am using Magento 2.3.2. I have a menu which is called **SALE** on my website. At the moment when you click on it, it shows all the product which are on sale. Is there a way to add sub-menus to it? For example:

> SALE -> Women | Men | Kids

and when you click on the respective category, to display only the products which are on sale from this category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Magento Luma with data, you have an example for this.

In the admin you just have to create your category SALE and create sub categories Women | Men | Kids.
Check the button "Include in Menu" for all of them, save, clean your cache and it will be displayed in front.

[image: Admin config]

[image: Frontend]

Comment: Great, before testing it would this add products which have Special price only, or it will display all the products which are under that specific category, let's say Women. Because I have a category which is Women and under it I have products on Sale and products which have just a regular price.

Comment: You have to add all the products on sale in this category. You can keep products in both categories, they will be displayed in the categories Women and in the Sale/Women